# Apache Rewrite rule with decode url

Tags: apache

I have a basic rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^/v1/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

Rewrite is working fine, but I have a issue with a request which is coming to the apache.

```
https://example.com/v1/test/bd95f52d72942198eb84e1b6998a6259/phone_numbers/%2B61180087654
```

Apache is decoding this URL to

```
https://example.com/v1/test/bd95f52d72942198eb84e1b6998a6259/phone_numbers/+61180087654
```

I want apache should pass the same request to my code. I don't want + with number. What should I change to get the expected result.

Thanks

Comment: These URL-s are equivalent. Plus sign in path component must be treated literally. The real problem is in the code that decodes the phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have some other reason to use rewrite, try this instead of `RewriteRule ...`

```
ProxyPass        /v1/ http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /v1/ http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/
```

(ProxyPass should also have performance benefits over rewrite, in some cases)